# Detect latest signal on the chart

Tags: pine-script

I have a question about the indicators, the ones that can repaint.

This indicator seems good but the problem is that, sometimes it changes suddenly, and last real signal on chart disappears, but we do not receive any new signal for continuing previous wave trend and we lose trend wave.

***So, I want to set up a warning to check at each -real- candlestick, if the last dot on real candle or on nearest historical candle is green, red, orange or purple?*** How I can achieve this?

I will be very grateful if you can guide me.

Answer (score 0):

The variable [`barstate.isconfirmed`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_barstate%7Bdot%7Disconfirmed) becomes `true` if the script is calculating the last (closing) update of the current bar. The next script calculation will be on the new bar data. By adding that condition to your `plot()` functions, it makes sure that no dots are drawn during the formation of the bar.

```
plot(d, color=white)
plot(barstate.isconfirmed ? bulldiv : na, title = "Tops", color=green, style=circles, linewidth=4)//, offset= -1)
plot(barstate.isconfirmed ? beardiv : na, title = "Bottoms", color=red, style=circles, linewidth=4)//, offset= -1)

plot(barstate.isconfirmed and y10>y2 and oscMax and y3 < y4 ? d :na, title = "Bearish Divergence2", color=orange, style= circles, linewidth=4)
plot(barstate.isconfirmed and y9<y6 and oscMins and y7 > y8 ? d :na, title = "Bullish Divergence2", color=purple, style=circles, linewidth=4)
plot(barstate.isconfirmed and delayedlow<y6 and y7 > y8 ? d :na, title = "Bullish Divergence2", color=purple, style=circles, linewidth=4)
plot(barstate.isconfirmed and delayedhigh>y2 and y3 < y4 ? d :na, title = "Bearish Divergence2", color=orange, style= circles, linewidth=4)

plot(barstate.isconfirmed and long_term_div and oscMax and i and i2 ? d :na, title = "Bearish Divergence2", color=orange, style= circles, linewidth=4)
plot(barstate.isconfirmed and long_term_div and oscMins and i4 and i5 ? d : na, title = "Bullish Divergence2", color=purple, style=circles, linewidth=4)
plot(barstate.isconfirmed and long_term_div and i and i3 ? d :na, title = "Bearish Divergence2", color=orange, style= circles, linewidth=4)
plot(barstate.isconfirmed and long_term_div and i4 and i6 ? d : na, title = "Bullish Divergence2", color=purple, style=circles, linewidth=4)
```

Comment: @ Bjorn-Mistiaen, thanks but, ..., I think using barstate.isconfirmed
causes this indicator to not work in real time and wait for the candle to close, right?
Buy, I want to be able to react to the appearance of a new signal on real time candle, and if the new signal disappears from the real candle, the last and closest signal on the historical candle will be repeated.

Comment: Correct. `barstate.islast` waits for the candle to close. But the way you describe it, there'll always be a signal on the realtime bar. It'll either be the "live" signal, or the "last and closest" signal. How will you be able to differentiate between the two? I don't see the benefit really, because if it shows no signal, just look at the latest signal, and you'll have what you want.

Comment: Yes, exactly, let me explain it with an example,we have a red triangle on candle 40, after that on candle 46, indicator shows us a green triangle for 80 seconds, and we receive a notification for buy opportunity, but suddenly the trend wave changes and green triangle on chart disappears, last  triangle on chart (or nearest triangle to the real candle on chart) is a red triangle on candle 40, and the problem is, we do not receive any red triangle on candle 46 or even 47 again and the price goes down and down, and we lose trend wave. So, what I want?

Comment: in this story it should give us a buy notification for 80 second and after that it should search on historical candles until candle 40, to find last triangle and understands it is red and give us sell notification)

Comment: My previous comment still applies. There's no benefit to this. If no signal, or signal disappears, just look at the previous latest signal. In any case, you should've gone short on candle 40.

Comment: @Behnam-Maboudi can you please look at to this topic, maybe you have a good Idea.

Comment: @pinecoders-lucf can you please look at to this topic, maybe you have a good Idea.

Comment: if I do not receive new alert, after disappearing last alert suddenly I will not be aware about that until I look at to the chart myself. This is the benefit of this work. Please help me to find a solution for this, thanks.

Comment: Ok, so you have a red triangle on candle 40. After that, on candle 46, you have green triangle for 80 seconds. After those 80 seconds, the green candle disappears.Do you want that last red candle drawn then on candle 46? If yes, each "empty" space between candle 40 and 46 will have the red triangle from candle 40 repeated. There'll be no "empty" space anymore. But I have a feeling that's not what you want.

Comment: Hi, "so you have a red triangle on candle 40. After that, on candle 46, you have green triangle for 80 seconds. After those 80 seconds, the green candle disappears.Do you want that last red candle drawn then on candle 46?" Yes, exactly, and every time the trend wave changes again, it draw  the suitable triangle on the real candle. "If yes, each "empty" space between candle 40 and 46 will have the red triangle from candle 40 repeated. There'll be no "empty" space anymore. " no, it is not matter at all.

Comment: Hello, Can you please help me modify the code?