# First part of code works great and other part do not work at all (pine-script)

Tags: pine-script

I wrote a code with if circle in Pine-script. Can you tell me where is problem in my code the first part (B) works great and I receive regular alerts, but other parts (S, BS, SS) do not work at all.

***the Algorithmus is like this if T is not greater than 9, then B equals zero otherwise check L and M if (L < M and M > 80) ==>B equals zero, otherwise check Sol and E, if Sol > E then B equals one otherwise B equals zero.*** rest parts tries to doing something like this to evaluate S, Bs and SS.

I changed the code but still not working

Please do not hesitate to guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Second code:

```
var B = 0.0
var S = 0.0
var BS = 0.0
var SS = 0.0
 
x = if (((T) < 9) and ((L > M) or (M <= 80)) and (Sol > E))
    B := 1
else 
    B := 2


y = if (((T) >= 1) and ((L < d) or (d >= 20)) and (Sol < E))
    S := 1
else
    S := 2
```

First code:

```
var B = 0.0
var S = 0.0
var BS = 0.0
var SS = 0.0
 
x = T > 9
    var q = 0
    B := q
    
else if (L < M and M > 80)
    var q = 0
    B := q
else
    c = if Sol > E
        var q = 1
        B := q
    else
        var q = 0
        B := q
    c


y = if T < 1
    var u = 0
    S := u
    
else if (L > M and M < 20)
    var u = 0
    S := u
else
    h = if Sol < E
        var u = 1
        S := u
    else
        var u = 0
        S := u
    h

w = if T > 9
    var e = 1
    BS := e
else if (L < M and M > 80)
    var e = 1
    BS := e
else
    var e = 0
    BS := e
    
z = if T < 1
    var j = 1
    SS := j
else if (L > M and M < 20)
    var j = 1
    SS := j
else
    var j = 0
    SS := j
    
condition1 = B == 1
condition2 = S == 1
condition3 = BS == 1
condition4 = SS == 1
alertcondition(condition1, title='good', message='good!')
alertcondition(condition2, title='bad', message='bad!')
alertcondition(condition2, title='bs', message='bs!')
alertcondition(condition2, title='ss', message='ss!')`
```

Comment: @pinecoders-lucf why this does not work?!!!!!

Comment: Read Tips for [Debugging](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Debugging.html) .
Check what values your conditions take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var B = 0
  
if T <= 9
    B := 0
else 
    if (L < M and M > 80)
        B := 0
    else 
        if Sol > E
            B := 1
        else
            B := 0
```

OR

```
if not(T <= 9) and not(L < M and M > 80) and (Sol > E)
    B:=1
else
    B:=0
```

Comment: Thank you very much @AnyDozer, it works now , can you please look at my other topic too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65693171/detect-latest-signal-on-the-chart